# symfony2 nomaya bundle facebook button

Tags: symfony, twig

I installed [nomaya bundle](http://knpbundles.com/nomayann/NomayaSocialButtonsBundle) (social bundle) for my Symfony project, the button like on Facebook generates an error because I work on localhost, have you an idea of ​​what I should do?

This is my twig file :

```
{{ twitterButton()}}
{{ googleplusButton()}}
{{ facebookButton()}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I shouldn't answer this because I don't the reason behind it but nomaya bundle seems to work under 127.0.0.1 rather than localhost.

So changing the way you access your website would do it.

http://127.0.0.1/yourwebsite ✔

http://localhost/yourwebsite x